# When someone shares a Google doc or presentation with me, I no longer get an email notification. How can I fix this?

Tags: gmail, notifications, google-drive-sharing

When a teacher or peer shares a google doc, presentation, or spreadsheet with me, it no longer appears in my Gmail. I have checked my spam, trash, and all my folders. It used to send a notification, and the feature is still available for my peers. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to be fixed. The person who shares the file decides if he wants to send out a notification email or not.

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks for your advice! However, just now actually, my peer shared a document with (let's just say John) and I, and John got a notification and I did not.